# Kotlin Exposed (KTOR) SELECT last record in Table

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

How can I select last record in table from database in ktor?

my data class

```
data class ArticleInfoDTO(
    val id: Int,
    val likes: Int,
    val views: Int,
)
```

my function

```
object ArticlesInfo : Table("articles_info") {
    private val id = ArticlesInfo.integer("id")
    private val likes = ArticlesInfo.integer("likes")
    private val views = ArticlesInfo.integer("views")

    fun fetchArticleInfoLastRecord(): ArticleInfoDTO {
        return transaction {
            ArticlesInfo.select {  } // what should I write in curly braces?
        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data class ArticleInfoDTO(
    val id: Int,
    val likes: Int,
    val views: Int,
)

object ArticlesInfo : Table("articles_info") {
    private val id = ArticlesInfo.integer("id")
    private val likes = ArticlesInfo.integer("likes")
    private val views = ArticlesInfo.integer("views")

    fun fetchArticleInfoLastRecord(): ArticleInfoDTO? = transaction {
        ArticlesInfo.selectAll().lastOrNull()?.toArticleInfo()
    }

    private fun ResultRow.toArticleInfo() = ArticleInfoDTO(
        this[id],
        this[likes],
        this[views]
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This method is good, but choosing through the selectAll() function, if there are thousands of records in the table, won't it be memory intensive?

Comment: I think that's the only option.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise something like:

```kotlin
val lastInfo = ArticlesInfo.selectAll().orderBy(ArticlesInfo.id, SortOrder.DESC).limit(1).singleOrNull()?.toArticleInfo()
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is to run a raw query.
In your case it would look something like this

```
object ArticlesInfoTable : IntIdTable("articles_info") {
    val likes = integer("likes")
    val views = integer("views")
}

class ArticlesInfoEntity(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id){
    companion object: IntEntityClass<ArticlesInfoEntity>(ArticlesInfoTable)
    var likes by ArticlesInfoTable.likes
    var views by ArticlesInfoTable.views
}

fun getLastItem(): ArticlesInfoEntity{
    return transaction {
        var maxId = 1
        TransactionManager.current().exec("SELECT MAX(id) as MAX from 
            articles_info;") { rs ->
            while (rs.next()) {
                maxId = rs.getString("MAX").toInt()
            }
        }
        ArticlesInfoEntity.findById(maxId)!!
    }
}
```

In this case raw query is for MySql.